# doing classification on object of an image

Tags: matlab

I want to detect airplanes in some satellite images. I've done the below process:
1)with `detectMSERFeatures` command detect features of of image.
2) with `extractFeatures` extract them, that contains feature of buildings and airplanes. 
Now, I want to classify airplanes from others such as buildings, cars and etc.
The output of `extractFeatures` is **feature <571x64 single>** .
I know, I can use of learning algorithm such as SVM,and I have done skin detection project before. but for skin detection I had a dataset that contains some feature value that was separated to skin and non-skin form each other by value 1 and 2. 1 means skin and 2 means non-skin. and then I did classification with SVM.

But, here I think, I should make my dataset, but how separate airplanes from building and etc with this **feature <571x64 single>**?

```
regions = detectMSERFeatures(I);
[features, valid_corners] = extractFeatures(I,regions);
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware that this, as you posed, is a research question? Google, Microsoft, MIT, Oxford, they are researching how to do that. I am quite sure they wont suddenly post the code here in SO for you. In other words, your question is too broad, and its not about a programming problem! Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: may be I didn't ask my question clearly. My question is just about the output of these commands : "detectMSERFeature", "extractFeatures" to use of them for classification of objects.  somebodies who works with these commands could answer to me.

Comment: "about the output" is not a question!

Comment: I found that the "feature<571*64 single> " is feature of objects that was detected. each row is one object feature. but now my question is that how can I distinguish which row is for which object?

Comment: Let me reffer to you to my first comment in this thread, because that is the answer.

Comment: @hupaa You cannot know which row is which. I suggest that you read about supervised and unsupervised clustering. It would help you to understand what Ander means in his comments.